# Changing matrices into single lines of data

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have multiple matrices in a .txt file and I need each matrix to be in a single line. For example,
matrices.txt:

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6

3 4 5 6
2 3 2 5
2 3 4 5
2 3 5 6
2 3 4 5
...
```

What I would like is `modified_matrices.txt`:

```
1 2 3 4 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 2 3 2 5 2 3 4 5 2 3 5 6 2 3 4 5
...
```

There are about 1000 matrices in the file and they are not all integers (0.8888888889888).

Comment: What is the length of the longest resulting line? Some tools have line length limits.

Comment: Could you just replace newlines with a space, except for two newlines in a row?

Comment: Please read and **apply** the [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), particularly the parts about no distractions/no chit-chat, to future posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible `awk` solution could be:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = ""; } { $1 = $1; } 1' matrices.txt > modified_matrices.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

In Vi/Vim you can run simply:

```
:%j
```

to join all the lines together, or:

```
:%v/^$/-1j
```

to join all matrices separated by new line ([Join lines between a certain text pattern in Vim](https://superuser.com/q/420497/87805)).

If you need this done from the command line, try either:

```
ex -s +%j +"wq modified_matrices.txt" matrices.txt
```

to join all lines, or:

```
ex -s +'%v/^$/-1j' +'wq! modified_matrices.txt' matrices.txt
```

to join all matrices separated by new line:

Comment: Vim is just too powerful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a little bash script:

```
$ cat data
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6

3 4 5 6
2 3 2 5
2 3 4 5
2 3 5 6
2 3 4 5

$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    if [[ "${line}" = "" ]]; then
        echo ""
    else
        echo -n "${line} "
    fi
done
echo ""

$ bash foo.sh < data
1 2 3 4 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 2 3 2 5 2 3 4 5 2 3 5 6 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

- With `tr` and `sed`:

Replace all newlines with hashes (pick any other symbol that is not present in your matrices if you have hashes), then double hashes are to be newlines and single ones just spaces: (GNU`sed`)

```
 tr '\n' '#'  <file  | sed 's/##/\n/g;s/#/ /g'
```

POSIX `sed`

```
 tr '\n' '#'  <file  | sed 's/##/\
 /g;s/#/ /g'
```

- Regarding the size of the file:

Maybe you also want to split the file into matrix blocks - separate file for each, then reunite them. Note that this is a lot of read/write operations and should only be considered if the other solutions go beyond your RAM capacities.

```
csplit -b%04d -f file file '/^$/' '{*}'
```

I.e. split `file` into files named `fileXXXX` with `XXXX` continuous integer, as separation marker use empty lines `'/^$/'` ; do for all occasions `'{*}'`. Now reunite the files piece by piece with a shell script:

```
for f in file???? ; do 
  sed '/^$/d' $f | tr '\n' ' ' >> newmatrices
done
```

I.e. remove the empty lines we used as split markers before, then `tr`anslate newlines to spaces and append each line to the `newmatrices` output file.

Of course both the splitting and the reunification can be put in a single script.

Note that I am not aware if `csplit` has different standards on different systems.

Comment: `-b` and `{*}` are `gnu csplit` specific. With `tr` | `sed`  you may want to pick as delimiter some low ascii char like `\x02` that's unlikely to be found in a text file (instead of `#` as the file may already contain that char). There's also another potential issue when there's no trailing empty line after the last matrix then your output will not end with a newline character.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` only:

```
sed '/^$/!{H;$!d;};x;s/.//;y/\n/ /' infile > outfile
```

This accumulates non-empty lines in the hold space and deletes them if not the last line else it exchanges buffers, removes the leading newline and translates all newlines to spaces.
With blocks separated by an arbitrary number of empty lines, to collapse them into a single one:

```
sed '/^$/!{         # if line isn't empty
H                   # append to hold space
$!d                 # if it's not the last line, delete it
b end               # branch to label end (this happens only if on the last line)
}
//b end             # if line is empty, branch to label end
: end               # label end
x                   # exchange pattern space w. hold space
//d                 # if pattern space is an empty line, delete it; else
s/\n//              # remove the leading \newline
s/\n/ /g            # replace all remaining \newline chars with spaces
' infile > outfile
```

or, as a one-liner:

```
sed '/^$/!{H;$!d;$b end;};//b end;: end;x;//d;s/\n//;s/\n/ /g' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Another [gnu](/questions/tagged/gnu) [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) one-liner:

```
$ sed -rz 's/\n([^\n])/ \1/g;s/\n /\n/g' matrices.txt
1 2 3 4 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 2 3 2 5 2 3 4 5 2 3 5 6 2 3 4 5
$
```

Because the `-z` effectively causes sed to read the whole file as one line, then this will be less suitable for large input files.